# Possible to put a maximum on the amount of inputs I create

Tags: javascript

So I have input fields that I can create, but I don't want the user to be able to add more then 4 input fields for each targetted element. The reason is because it will mess up the front-end (I use a certain grid).

The code that creates the input fields:

```
function getAddBtn(target, i){
  var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary',
                'id': 'addBtn'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
 return addBtn;
}
```

is it possible to put a max on this function or do I have to provide other code? -> `getWordPartInput(i)`

just to be sure I added `getWordPartInput(i)`

```
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
 cValue = cValue || '';
 var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
'type': 'text',
'value': cValue,
'placeholder': 'Syllables',
'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID++ +']'
 });
 return wpInput;
}
```

Comment: What's `i` in `getAddBtn`?

Comment: that's targetting the ID